# For i in range(b) variable

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there anyway to store the input of the user in total for each amount of money raised?

```
 b=int(input("Please enter how many people have collected money: "))
 for i in range(b):
    a=int(input("Please enter the amount raised: "))
total =
```

Comment: PROTIP: Tag the question with the *language* you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list to store the values in:

```
b=int(input("Please enter how many people have collected money: "))
total = [0]*b
for i in range(b):
    a=int(input("Please enter the amount raised: "))
    total[i] = a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :
`
b=int(input("Please enter how many people have collected money: "))

total = []

for i in range(b):
    a=int(input("Please enter the amount raised: "))
    total.append (a)
print ("Total: " , sum(total))
`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use this:

```
b=int(input("Please enter how many people have collected money: "))
total=0
for i in range(b):
    total+=int(input("Please enter the amount raised: "))
```

This adds your given input on `total` every Iteration.